# magento 1.8 validation not working for new fields in custom contact form

Tags: forms, validation, contacts, magento-1.8

I am trying to validate my new fields in custom contact form, here is my link for the form:

http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/index.php/custom-contact/index/

I included the form id in the line: `var contactForm = new VarienForm('customcontacts', true);`

and I made every input with class like that:

```
<input class="required-entry input-fields" name="country" id="country" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('customcontacts')->__('Pays') ?>" value="" type="text" />
```

But when I try to submit without filling in these fields, it submitts the form and sending email without any error.

I hope any someone can help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `<form>` is defined between `<table>` and `<tr>`, which is not valid. That can mess up things. If you print out in a javascript console the content of your form `document.getElementById('customcontacts').outerHTML`, then you will see that it is empty.
Make sure that the `<form>` and `</form>` tags are in a valid place (usually when you look at the source of the page from firefox it marks invalid markups with red color). Then the validation should work.